# Upload video and share link - API?

Tags: ios, facebook, video, twitter, youtube

I am developing an app that shares video across several social sites (Facebook, Twitter, Pinterest and SMS and Email).

Not all of these services does video upload (like Twitter), and sharing the video on multiple networks is time consuming for the user.

I am looking for a service that will allow users to upload videos, and the service will then provide a url the user can share on the social sites. It would be great if this is possible without having to create user accounts, but only one developer account.

All videos will be less than 3 minutes in length.

Hope this makes sense.

I have been thinking about creating an app linked YouTube account, but that might cause problems since users can upload all kinds of things and that might get the account shut down.

Hoping to keep costs down on this one, and not have to host all the videos on my own servers (AWS or something like that).

Hope you have got some ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is not a programming or even a technical question.

viddur.com might do what you want — its a startup and they probably don't have a public api yet, though. Other than that, no one will offer you this service for free. It cost between 0.01-03 cents to encode video (and you have to do it multiple times per video to support varios platforms). Encoding and hosting video is not as cheap as static images. You're basically trying to create a product around a free service that doesn't exist.

TL:DR: Abandon your idea, and only post technical questions to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks Mauvis, diden't know where else to ask it, since it might get technical (with different kinds of implementation). And thanks for the viddur link, I will look into that!